# Load service data into angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component which takes care of drawing two lists, but in the component there is no data so nothing is drawn.

myController

```
function loadAllData() {
                Admin.getAllSettings()
                .then(function (settings) {
                    $scope.settings = settings.data;
                })
            }
```

myComponent

```
{
        bindings: {
            selectedData: '=',
            availableData: '<'
        },
        templateUrl: 'global/twoListSelector.directive.html',
        controller: function () {
            var me = this;

            console.log(me);
        }
    }
```

myView

```
<two-side-selector selectedData="doctorProperties" availableData="settings"></two-side-selector>
```

In the console.log the output for `me.settings` is undefined. Shouldn't the digest cycle update the setting property so it gets to the component? The service is returning data correctly but it is not getting to the component

I am using angular 1.5.9

Comment: Where do you call the `loadAllData()` function on your `scope`? It's normal that there is no data if you don't call the data function on the myComponent scope.

Comment: The loadAllData is called in a parent controller lets say controller 'A', the controller A is in the scope of my view, so that `availableData="settings"` should refer to the data returned by service

Comment: did you try to add `console.log($scope.settings)` in your promise success handler, does it print some datas ?

Comment: It does print data, but my error was what @Antonio suggested. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use selected-data and available-data attributes at markup:

```
<two-side-selector selected-data="doctorProperties" available-data="settings"></two-side-selector>
```

AngularJS convert dash-separated attributes to camel-case by itself

Comment: It works! Forgot about that I thought it was only for directive names